# ASP.NET Core Identity & Cookies

Tags: session, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core site using AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.1 and cookies to authorize/authenticate my users.  No matter what I choose as my setting in the code below, the cookie expires after about 20 minutes and I can't figure why.  The website will then no longer work unless you close the browser and clear the history/cookies.  Any ideas?

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
{
    //  Require a confirmed email in order to log in
    config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

app.UseIdentity();

//  Add cookie middleware to the configure an identity request and persist it to a cookie.
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie",
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/"),
    AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/"),
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
    SlidingExpiration = true,

});
```

I also have some razor code that controls whether to show the admin menu on the _layout page.  This crashes when the cookie expires as the users suddenly has no claims.  Is there a better way to handle this?

```
// If user is admin then show drop down with admin navigation
@if (User.HasClaim(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"))
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @*etc*@
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: could you also post your AddIdentity section block?

Comment: I have updated my question with the AddIdentity block from ConfigureServices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a separate CookieAuthentication middleware when you are using ASPNET identity. `UseIdentity()` will do that for you and generate a cookie. You can set the `"cookie options"` in the AddIdentity block of the application like so:

```
     services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
            {
                //  Require a confirmed email in order to log in
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;

               // Your Cookie settings
              config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
              config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn";
              config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LogoutPath = "/Account/LogOut";
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Also, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34981457/1137785, it gives a background of this sort of a scenario with a very good explanation.

Comment: Thanks @Muqeet.  Your response helped me to solve my problem!

Comment: @muqeetKhan In [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore1x#tabpanel_yS0QDAFpXJ-1_aspnetcore1x) new ASP.NET article they are using the following to setup the options. What is the difference in your approach and the article's approach, do you know? `// Configure Identity
    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {.....}`

Comment: @nam just different extension methods. In my example, I am using the extension method that takes the `options` object which is then configured in DI within the method. In the link you gave, they are just doing it separately. Its open source yay! look here on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/patch/1.1.4/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs)

Comment: Either I am blind, or in 3.1 `config.Cookies` is gone. How should I configure the `LoginPath` now?

Comment: It's been moved to services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(configure => { ... });

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that I was persisting data to a cookie with different settings.

Not sure if it's the proper way to do it, but I was able to solve the problem by using both services.AddIdentity and app.UseCookieAuthentication as below.

In ConfigureServices, set the cookie for log in:

```
        //  set the cookie for sign in
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
        {               
            //  Require a confirmed email in order to log in
            config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            // Cookie settings
            config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(10);
            config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn";
            config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LogoutPath = "/Account/LogOut";
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

In Configure set the cookie scheme used to persist claims:

```
        //  Add cookie middleware to the configure an identity request and persist it to a cookie.
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/"),
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/"),
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            //ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(10),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
        });
```

In the log in method, persist the claims:

```
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Cookie", userPrincipal);
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use this way in order to use SignInManager in future:

```
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<Server04DbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Local"));
    }).AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
        options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
    }).AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddEntityFrameworkStores<Server04DbContext>();

    builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Auth/Login");
        options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Auth/Logout");
        options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/AccessDenied");

        options.Cookie = new()
        {
            Name = "IdentityCookie",
            HttpOnly = true,
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
            SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
        };
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
    });
```