# ASP.NET Identity - how to extend the login expiration time

Tags: asp.net, session, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-security

My `ASP.NET Core 1.1.1` app is logging out after about 30 minutes. I'm using some session variables and have installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session package` and have configured the app as shown below. Have set the session expiration time to 2 hours. From what I've read the Authentication Cookie time by default is 14 days so that should not be an issue. **Question**: It seems I may be missing something here. What needs to be done to make the app not logout before 2 hours? What are the possible causes and what is a possible solution?

**Note**: The app is running on `IIS 10 on windows 10`. The Application Pool for the app is set to `Not Managed Code` and it's default idle time out is 20 minutes with idle timtout-action set to `Terminate`. But from what I've heard the IIS Application Pool Idle Time-out Settings play no role in ASP.NET Core.

**Startup.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MyProjName.Data;
using MyProjName.Models;
using MyProjName.Services;

namespace MyProjName
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
                builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
            }

            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connection = @"Server=MyWin10Machine;Database=MySQL20012Db;User Id=TestUSer;Password=TestPassword";

            services.AddDbContext<MyProjNameContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

            // Add framework services.
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
                options.CookieHttpOnly = true;
            }); //extended the session timout to 2 hours. Default is 20 minutes

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
            services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseIdentity();
            app.UseSession(); //must come before app.UseMvc()

            // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @BlakeConnally The link you referred is not relevant here at all. That link is about very old legacy ASP.NET 2.0 - that is way before [ASP.NET Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity) was introduced.

Comment: @nam You might want to look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45699799/296861)

Comment: @Win Thanks. Your solution worked. So it means Application Pool Idle-Timeout settings do play a role in ASP.NET Core deployed to IIS. You may want to convert your comment to a `Response` with some additional comments so others can benefit with it, as well. I'll mark that as an `Answer`.