# How to keep the session alive in dot net core 2.1

Tags: c#, angular, session, .net-core

We are using the dot net core 2.1, with angular 5. We save the user id and user name etc info in sessions for authentication. But the problem is, after sometime the system gets the user logged out. Although, we make some server side requests during that time. Is there any way to keep the session alive, until the browser session regardless if user makes some server side or not. Even if the user makes server side request, when open the ink in new tab it will ask to login again.

Comment: Keep the credentials in local storage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cookie Authentication expiring too soon in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45595615/cookie-authentication-expiring-too-soon-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

Save credential in local storage. Below is the angular code example

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TokenType } from './tokenResponseType';

@Injectable()
export class TokenManager {

  private _tokenKey: string = 'bapp_key';

  storeToken(tokenDetail: TokenType) {
    localStorage.setItem(this._tokenKey, JSON.stringify(tokenDetail));
  }

  getToken() {
    var tokenDetails = localStorage.getItem(this._tokenKey);
    return JSON.parse(tokenDetails);
  }
}
```