# .net core 3.1 identity keeps forcing user to log in after short time using Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to get a net core 3.1 with identity setup with Razor pages where all pages require login and I want the login to last on the browser for 300 days. 
I have tried updating my startup.cs file to so that the login will last for a long time.  But no matter what I have tried the login will not last more than 20 or 30 minutes. Below is my current startup.cs file.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using IKDataWeb.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using IKDataWeb.Services;

namespace IKDataWeb
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                    sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(900)
                    ));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => {
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
            })
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(300);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });

            services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorOptions(options =>
            {
                options.PageViewLocationFormats.Add("/Pages/Shared/Components/Master/{0}.cshtml");
            });

            services.AddControllers(config =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                 .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                 .Build();
                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });

            services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

            services.AddSingleton<IEmailConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailConfiguration").Get<EmailConfiguration>());
            services.AddTransient<IEmailService, EmailService>();
            services.AddTransient<IFilterProducts, FilterProducts>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It could be an issue with IIS, if that's what you're using.  See this link regarding that:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45595615/cookie-authentication-expiring-too-soon-in-asp-net-core

Comment: I tried this it didn't help.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59638797/11398810) help you?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it turns out that Rono was correct!
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56564858/12567687) did the trick.

Thanks for your help!