# How to change cookie expiration time when signin with PasswordSignInAsync?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

How I can update Cookie Expiration time when signin with below code

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, isPersistent, lockoutOnFailure);
```

Like can use with SingInAsyn

```
 var authProps = new AuthenticationProperties
 {
      IsPersistent = isPersistent,
      ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5)
 };
 await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, authProps, authenticationMethod);
```

Comment: think this may help you, check the question and answer
[ExpireTimeSpan ignored after regenerateIdentity / validateInterval duration in MVC Identity (2.0.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23983726/9988501)

Comment: Did the following answer resolve your issue?https://stackoverflow.com/a/59744231/11398810

Comment: @Rena, no it doesn’t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't found the way to pass authenticationProperties but below code works. Need to override the SignInWithClaimsAsync method of SingInManager class

```
public override async Task SignInWithClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user, AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Security.Claims.Claim> additionalClaims)
{
    if (authenticationProperties != null && authenticationProperties.IsPersistent)
    {
        authenticationProperties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30);
    }

    await base.SignInWithClaimsAsync(user, authenticationProperties, additionalClaims);
}
```