# ASP.NET Core Session Timeout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, session, asp.net-identity, session-cookies

I remember we have used session.timeout in ASP.NET to change the session timeout which was 20 minutes if not changed.

I tried to change the session time out in ASP.NET Core 3.1 in Startup.cs but nothing happens. I use Identity for operators and set the Idle Timeout for 5 hours 'I Think' but operators sign out after 1-2 minutes and should re-login hundreds of times for completing an article.

```
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(5);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

What am I missing ??

Comment: Can you provide the rest of your startup file.

Comment: If you would like to change Identity expiration time, just use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59638797/11398810).

Comment: @Mertez; Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Comment: @XAMT It didn't solve my problem, My logged in Identity users log off after 2-3 minutes and none of the articles including your answer solved my issue

Comment: @Mertez; Add a name to your cookie and check it before/after time out. Use EditThisCookie chrome extension and like so to check the cookie. Check Expiration and Session. Session must not have check.

Answer (score 1):

For using session state in an ASP.NET Core you need to add the session middleware to your pipeline.

**important:** The order of middleware is the key. Call UseSession between UseRouting and UseEndpoints.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSession();
}
```

More info : 
[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseHttpContextItemsMiddleware();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are using identity then use the following code in your `startup.cs` class after `services.AddIdentity()`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...

        services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(o =>
        {
            o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(5);
        });
    }
```

Comment: I already have this `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>...)` should I still use the `AddAuthentication().AddCookie(options=>...)`

Comment: No need for AddAuthentication().AddCookie(options=>...). Your sessions expires in 5 minutes or earlier?

Comment: I test in local host, it went beyond 15 minutes, but real user in real system, report that when they write article, or go offline, they get logged out in few minutes, when we asked what was the minimum time , they approximately pointed 10 minutes

Comment: Have you checked your idle timeout of Application Pool?

Comment: you mean application pool getting reset? isn't that application wide? you mean the config in IIS, right?

Comment: How do I configure idle timeout of Application Pool? @ZubairRana

Comment: And how can I be sure that it is happening due to Application Pool or just a session timeout?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
}
```

The preceding code sets a short timeout to simplify testing.

The order of middleware is important. Call UseSession after UseRouting and before UseEndpoints. See Middleware Ordering.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSession();
}
```

`HttpContext.Session` is available after session state is configured.

`HttpContext.Session` can't be accessed before `UseSession` has been called.

A new session with a new session cookie can't be created after the app has begun writing to the response stream. The exception is recorded in the web server log and not displayed in the browser.