# ASP.NET Core MVC Identity - User randomly logging out

Tags: authentication, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I have looked all over, but have found no answer that works for me. Whenever I am working in the localhost, my user never gets logged out and the session is remembered so I don't have to log in again. However, when I publish it (I use HostGator's ASP.NET hosting) the user gets randomly logged out after a few minutes or after an HTTP request. Some answers I have seen include HostGator needing to have an ASP.NET Core hosting module, my web.config using a machine key, and using `services.AddSession`, but I haven't had any luck.

Here's my Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AuthDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
            );

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
            );

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 10;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvcCore();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddMvcCore().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

            services.AddMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(6);
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            // Authentication must always go before Authorization
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                 name: "default",
                 pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
```

Here's my Login method in the Account controller:

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel lvm)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(lvm.Email, lvm.Password, lvm.RememberMe, false);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return Redirect(lvm.ReturnURL);
                }

                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid Login Attempt");
            }
            return View(lvm);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this question, I think it needs to be tested before conclusions can be drawn. Best if you have Windows Server or VM, if not, install IIS locally, remember to set the website to Always on. You also can [set environment to Production](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-set-the-hosting-environment-in-asp-net-core/).

You need to deploy the same code locally in IIS and use the same method to see if you will encounter the same problem.

**1. If the problem recurs, then the code needs to be optimized.**

**2. If it works fine locally, then we have reason to suspect that something is wrong with HostGator's ASP.NET hosting.**

#### Suggestion

[Use Data Protection to persist the keys if IIS application pool recycles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71915822/7687666)