# Why User.Identity.IsAuthenticated setting to false after some time in Identity Cookie based authentication

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm developing an API in asp.net core 2.0 with EF core. I have configured identity cookie authentication in `startup.cs` as follows.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.Name = "example-cookie-name";
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14); 
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(14);
});
```

When a user log in to the api, it creates a cookie setting the expiry time as `1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z` (extracted from Chrome brower F12). After some time(20-30)min later, all the claims are no longer exists.

Also, `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` has set to `false`. Because of that, I'm not able to resolve the database context(utilizing claim values).

Is this the expected behavior in asp.net identity core? If so, how can I use a middleware solution to delete the cookie or some other workaround to do that? because once the cookie is deleted user can re-login.

**Content updated**

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Also in

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
 ...
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseContextAuthorizeValidatorMiddleware();
 app.UseMvc();
}
```

Inside `UseContextAuthorizeValidatorMiddleware`, I checked this,

```
public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
{
  var isAuthenticated = httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
 //...
  return _next(httpContext);
}
```

Comment: Note: you shouldn't be using `options.Cookie.Expiration`. It was replaced by `ExpireTimeSpan` (which you are also setting). Are you calling `app.UseAuthentication`? Are you calling `services.AddIdentity` to add identity or `services.AddAuthentication` with `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` to map to `HttpContext.User`? Take a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-2.1#cookie-based-authentication).

Comment: @Dean, Updated the question content,

Comment: Interesting. Are you saying that for the first 20 minutes after a user logs in, `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is true? Then after 20 minutes it's set to false?

Comment: Also - check [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44503079/3718246) out. I believe that might be a good fix for your situation as well.

Comment: No Dean. You can't use `cookie` options inside `services.AddIdentity`. It has been removed from core 2.0. In 1.xx it's possible according to the documentation.

Comment: I spent the half day trying to get this working, until I found out I left this line, that override the identity customization:
`services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();`