# ASP.NET Core Authentication cookie does not expire

Tags: c#, authentication, iis, asp.net-core

The cookie does not expire when deploying the application in IIS. When doing the testing using VS + IIS Express, everything works as expected. Please see setup above.

In Startup:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
 {
   AuthenticationScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
   AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
   ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3),
   CookieSecure = env.IsDevelopment() ? CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest : 
   CookieSecurePolicy.Always
 });
```

In Controller:

```
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(GetUserClaims(claims, response.ContentObject.Jwt, username), CookieName));
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(CookieName, principal);
```

Comment: This will helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979680/asp-net-core-mvc-setting-expiration-of-identity-cookie/34981457

Comment: I am not using identity server. I am using only the authentication cookie. Which response would help?

Comment: How did you test the cookies expire? For `CookieAuthenticationOptions`, there is `SlidingExpiration`  which default is true and to instruct the middleware to re-issue a new cookie with a new expiration time any time it processes a request which is more than halfway through the expiration window. I suggest you try set `SlidingExpiration` as false.