# Long living web page with azure AD authentication, times out

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I have really tried to google this, but with no luck..
I have a long living web-page that periodically loads data from the server. (will change this to websockets at a later stage).

The server is based on .netcore 3.1 and I use AzureAD multi-tennent authentication.

The issue for me is that the cookie that is set in the browser 'times' out after 30 something minutes, and then my `fetch` will not work any more.
I am using standard azure AD auth on the server.

I am pretty sure I have miss configured something, or miss understood something about the setup.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a resource describing how to do something like this.

Comment: Have you tried crawling requests? Did you report any errors? I need more information from you.

Comment: Are you still facing issue here?

Comment: Yes, but needed some summer vacation :D  any good hints.

Comment: Please check if this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979680/asp-net-core-mvc-setting-expiration-of-identity-cookie) can help.

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly the same, but close enough..

Comment: Hi Petter, did it resolve your issue?

Comment: More or less :D

Comment: Thank you for the update. Do let us know if you need further assistance.