# Set ASP.NET Core Identity session no expired

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I would like to set never expired for my asp.net core identity. How can I do that? The code as below...

```
         services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
        });
```

Comment: What version of .net core you use, maybe you can set the time very long, you can read this post, maybe it will be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979680/asp-net- core-mvc-setting-expiration-of-identity-cookie/34981457

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [`TimeSpan.MaxValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.maxvalue). It is approximately 20 000 years, which seems long enough...

This bigger question is *why* do you want this. Are you maybe looking for the [`SlidingExpiration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.slidingexpiration) property? Which will "re-issue a new cookie with a new expiration time any time it processes a request which is more than halfway through the expiration window"?