# how to set Session Timeout in web.config in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, iis, timeout

If the user pauses for more than 20 minutes and does not work with the site, the site will remove her from the account and the user must log in again.

Host support says use Session Timeout in web.config.I tried many ways but failed for example:

```
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(6);
    });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(360);
            options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
```

### my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ModiranVira.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: DCDBD7A7-41AE-4CFE-A641-D1F9750A311C-->
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979680/asp-net-core-mvc-setting-expiration-of-identity-cookie suggests that `ExpireTimeSpan` only works with persistent logins.

Comment: can I use this Answer in this link for asp.net core https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205828/how-to-set-session-timeout-in-web-config

Answer (score 0):

There's a Session State module on IIS. When you choose state server, it will allow you set session time-out.

[image]

Or you can set in ASP module.

[image]

Finally check your Application Pool's idle timeout that application pool idle timeout too matches your session timeout.

[image]

Comment: But my site is on a real host (Plesk) and the site support says you have to set the Session Timeout

Comment: can I use this Answer in this link for asp.net core https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205828/how-to-set-session-timeout-in-web-config

Comment: You can try it.